# Get all static data attributes of HTML element without internaly binded data

Tags: javascript, jquery, custom-data-attribute

With `$('.selector').data()` we can collect all data props of element. However, in result set will be not only data-attributes, but also all dynamic data too (in my particular situation from jQuery UI).

I am watching for elegant way to collect only "static" data-attributes from element.

Comment: If you are concerned only with the modern browsers then you can use the [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)

Comment: console example: `JSON.stringify($0.dataset)`

Comment: Dataset -- no IE 10 support. For me it is still modern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.selector').clone().data()
```

jQuery clone() method by default do not copy dynamic data, but leave static data-* attributes.

> **.clone( [withDataAndEvents ] [, deepWithDataAndEvents ] )**
>
> > withDataAndEvents (default: false)
> >     deepWithDataAndEvents (default: value of withDataAndEvents)

[API Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/clone/)